# How to write filters for methods (not fields) in Active Admin?

Tags: methods, filter, customization, filtering, activeadmin

I have an Active Admin index page for some resource.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Request do
  index do
    column :created_at
    column :content
    column "Approved", :approved?
    default_actions
  end

  filter :created_at
  filter :content
  filter :approved?
end
```

The problem is it doesn't generate filter for `approved?` request (but it generates column properly). I think it's because `approved` is a method and returns true if `approved_at` isn't `nil`. How can I write filter in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to create a filter button using scopes:

```
# model/request.rb
scope :approved, where("approved_at IS NOT NULL")

# or...if you have other default values on approved_at column you can try this
scope :approved, where("approved IS NOT", nil)
scope :approved, where("approved IS NOT ?", "")

#app/admin/requests.rb
scope :approved
```

Some more info on scopes in Active Admin: http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#scoping_the_queries

Comment: `def approved? if approved_at then true else false end end`

Comment: I added the button to filter on approved by scoping on approved_at column. Please try :)